# Is it bad to convert sqlite database to server (database)?

Tags: sqlite

I am using a c program to write/delete 1-2MB of data periodically (10min) to sqlite3 database. The program also act as a read only database for my node.js web server to output Restful APIs. (I can not use node.js modules because node.js web server is on different machine)

In documentation its mentioned that in client/server architechture RDBMS might be good but that point is not put strongly

<strike>I am using a c program to act as a server to answer web servers request as well as other processes on different machine. The system require small data (~2-5Mb) frequently (every 5min).</strike>

**If it is not good to use sqlite as client server database How can I convince my manager?**

**If its okay then why do they not have a standard server plugin?**

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). Are you asking this becaue you are seeing some specific issue?

Comment: I am just curious why it does not have a server functionality/addon? No problem yet (I haven't played much) but they should have a simple addon/documentation to handle concurrency. I will post the problems if found

Comment: SQLite is an *embedded* database; its whole architecture is based on being integrated with the application.

Comment: Your description is unclear. Do the "other processes on different machine" access the database, or your server program?

Comment: Other server(my node.js server) which is on different machine connect to my c program using tcp socket to query sqlite database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38002/discussion-between-gaurav-and-cl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) speaks about a client/server architecture, it says:

> If you have many client programs accessing a common database over a network

This applies to whatever program(s) that access the database *directly*. (In the case of SQLite, this would imply that you have a networked *file server*, and that multiple clients access the database file directly over the network.)

If you have a single process that accesses the database file, then you do *not* have a client/server architecture as far as the database is concerned.
If there are other clients that access your server program, this has no effect on your database.